# Problem with "select All" option

Tags: javascript

The problem with the below code is that Select All options works very well in Mozilla and not in Internet Explorer.

```
<!-- 
Document   : DG
Created on : Sep 11, 2008, 12:48:37 PM
Author     : padmaja
-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var months = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var daysInMonth = new Array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
var days = new Array("S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S");

today = new getToday(); 
var element_id;

function getDays(month, year) 
{
// Test for leap year when February is selected.
if (1 == month)
    return ((0 == year % 4) && (0 != (year % 100))) ||
        (0 == year % 400) ? 29 : 28;
else
    return daysInMonth[month];
}

function getToday()
{
// Generate today's date.
this.now = new Date();
this.year = this.now.getFullYear() ; // Returned year XXXX
this.month = this.now.getMonth();
this.day = this.now.getDate();
}


function newCalendar() 
{
var parseYear = parseInt(document.all.year  [document.all.year.selectedIndex].text);

var newCal = new Date(parseYear , document.all.month.selectedIndex, 1);
var day = -1;
var startDay = newCal.getDay();
var daily = 0; 

today = new getToday(); // 1st call
if ((today.year == newCal.getFullYear() ) &&   (today.month == newCal.getMonth()))
   day = today.day;
// Cache the calendar table's tBody section, dayList.
var tableCal = document.all.calendar.tBodies.dayList;

var intDaysInMonth =
   getDays(newCal.getMonth(), newCal.getFullYear() );

for (var intWeek = 0; intWeek < tableCal.rows.length;  intWeek++)
       for (var intDay = 0;
         intDay < tableCal.rows[intWeek].cells.length;
         intDay++)
 {
      var cell = tableCal.rows[intWeek].cells[intDay];

      // Start counting days.
      if ((intDay == startDay) && (0 == daily))
         daily = 1;

      // Highlight the current day.
      cell.style.color = (day == daily) ? "red" : "";
      if(day == daily)
      {
            document.all.todayday.innerText= "Today: " +  day + "/" + 
                (newCal.getMonth()+1) + "/" + newCal.getFullYear() ;
      }
      // Output the day number into the cell.
      if ((daily > 0) && (daily <= intDaysInMonth))
         cell.innerText = daily++;
      else
         cell.innerText = "";
   }

}

 function getTodayDay()
 {
            document.all[element_id].value = today.year + "/" + (today.month+1) + 
                "/" + today.day; 
            //document.all.calendar.style.visibility="hidden";
            document.all.calendar.style.display="none";
            document.all.year.selectedIndex =100;   
            document.all.month.selectedIndex = today.month; 
 }

    function getDate() 
     {
        // This code executes when the user clicks on a day
        // in the calendar.
        if ("TD" == event.srcElement.tagName)
           // Test whether day is valid.
           if ("" != event.srcElement.innerText)
           { 
             var mn = document.all.month.selectedIndex+1;
             var Year = document.all.year [document.all.year.selectedIndex].text;
            document.all[element_id].value=Year +"-"+mn+"-"+event.srcElement.innerText;
             document.all.calendar.style.display="none";
         }
     }

function GetBodyOffsetX(el_name, shift)
{
var x;
var y;
x = 0;
y = 0;

var elem = document.all[el_name];
do 
{
    x += elem.offsetLeft;
    y += elem.offsetTop;
    if (elem.tagName == "BODY")
        break;
    elem = elem.offsetParent; 
} while  (1 > 0);

shift[0] = x;
shift[1] = y;
return  x;
}   

function SetCalendarOnElement(el_name)
{
if (el_name=="") 
el_name = element_id;
var shift = new Array(2);
GetBodyOffsetX(el_name, shift);
document.all.calendar.style.pixelLeft  = shift[0]; //  - document.all.calendar.offsetLeft;
document.all.calendar.style.pixelTop = shift[1] + 25 ;
}



function ShowCalendar(elem_name)
{
    if (elem_name=="")
    elem_name = element_id;

    element_id  = elem_name; // element_id is global variable
    newCalendar();
    SetCalendarOnElement(element_id);
    //document.all.calendar.style.visibility = "visible";
    document.all.calendar.style.display="inline";
}

function HideCalendar()
{
//document.all.calendar.style.visibility="hidden";
document.all.calendar.style.display="none";
}

function toggleCalendar(elem_name)
{
//if (document.all.calendar.style.visibility == "hidden")
if(document.all.calendar.style.display=="none")
    ShowCalendar(elem_name);
else 
    HideCalendar();
}
-->
</script>

<style>
.today {COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold}
.days {COLOR: navy; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-ALIGN: center}
.dates {COLOR: black; FONT-F

AMILY: sans-serif; FONT-SIZE: 10pt}
</style>
</head>

    <body bgcolor="#FFF8DC"> 
     <h5>Diesel Generators</h5><br><br>
         <br>
             <br>
                 <script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG1');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG2');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG3');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG4');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
     checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG5');
  for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select  All<br/>

<form method=POST action="DGUsageServlet">

<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="DG1">DG1
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="DG2">DG2
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="DG3">DG3
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="DG4">DG4
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="DG5">DG5

<br>
<br>
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="StartDate">
    <a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="toggleCalendar('StartDate')">StartDate</a>
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="EndDate">
     <a href="JavaScript:;" onClick="toggleCalendar('EndDate')">EndDate</a>
<input name=plotgraph value=plotgraph align="CENTER" type=submit>
</form>
<TABLE bgColor=#ffffff border=1 cellPadding=0 cellSpacing=3 id=calendar style="DISPLAY: none; POSITION: absolute; Z-INDEX: 4">
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD colSpan=7 vAlign=center>
    <!-- Month combo box -->
    <SELECT id=month onchange=newCalendar()> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Output months into the document.
        // Select current month.
        for (var intLoop = 0; intLoop < months.length; intLoop++)
            document.write("<OPTION " + (today.month == intLoop ? "Selected" : "") + ">" + months[intLoop]);
        </SCRIPT>
    </SELECT> 
    <!-- Year combo box -->
    <SELECT id=year onchange=newCalendar()> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Output years into the document.
        // Select current year.
        for (var intLoop = 1900; intLoop < 2028; intLoop++)
            document.write("<OPTION " + (today.year == intLoop ? "Selected" : "") + ">" + intLoop);
        </SCRIPT>
    </SELECT> 

    </TD>
  </TR>



  <TR class=days>
    <!-- Generate column for each day. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Output days.
    for (var intLoop = 0; intLoop < days.length; intLoop++)
        document.write("<TD>" + days[intLoop] + "</TD>");
    </SCRIPT>
  </TR>


  <TBODY class=dates id=dayList onclick="getDate('')" vAlign=center>
  <!-- Generate grid for individual days. -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    for (var intWeeks = 0; intWeeks < 6; intWeeks++)
    {
        document.write("<TR>");
        for (var intDays = 0; intDays < days.length; intDays++)
            document.write("<TD>" +intDays+ "</TD>");

        document.write("</TR>");
    }
  </SCRIPT>

  <!-- Generate today day. --></TBODY>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD class=today colSpan=5 id=todayday onclick=getTodayDay()></TD>
    <TD align=right colSpan=2><A href="javascript:HideCalendar();"><SPAN style="COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 10px"><B>Hide</B></SPAN></A></TD>
  </TR>
  </TBODY>

</TABLE>



</body>
</html>
```

Please guide me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is using document.all everywhere please *don't use it*, you should instead use document.getElementById

IE 4 introduced the document.all DOM. Soon after that the standard DOM method getElementById was introduced and is therefore available in *all* modern browsers.

For example:

```
document.all.calendar.style.display="none";
```

Should be now:

```
document.getElementById('calendar').style.display="none";
```

Comment: That code made old memories came to my mind, IE vs. Netscape, document.all vs. document.layers wars... so much time has passed....

Answer (score 0):

The `for each(var in array/object)` construct is a relatively new addition to Javascript.  Don't use it.  IE is probably choking on it.

Instead, use the older (and universally supported) `for (var in array/object)` construct.

Better, don't ever use the `for (var in x)` construct on arrays, and [rather use them only on objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in#Description).

Here's my rewrite:

```
function toggle(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('DG1');
    for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
        checkbox.checked = source.checked;
    }
    // etc...
}
```